# NSPredicate substring in string

Tags: ios, swift

I want to show all items where `value1` contains `value2`. I tried this:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Product")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "value1 CONTAINS[cd] value2")
```

`value1`, `value2` - current object values, it is not variables

But i got error:

> Unable to parse the format string

Why it doesn't allow me to do this ?

Comment: I strongly assume that you can't use "CONTAINS" with the RHS being a property, only with constant strings on the RHS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this predicate:

```
 let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "value1 CONTAINS[cd] %@", value2)
```

As were investigated during communication with developer. Issue is in data that is saved to the database. In his case data is saved with quotes ("") and `NSPredicate(format: "value1 CONTAINS[cd] %@", value2)` is working with errors due to that issue.

Comment: Does this case insensitive ?

Comment: and i don't have value2. value2 - it is current object value

Comment: @Arti String comparisons are by default case and diacritic sensitive. You can modify an operator using the key characters c and d within square braces to specify case and diacritic insensitivity respectively, for example firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] $FIRST_NAME.

Comment: @Arti value2 it is a value you compare

Comment: i want to compare current object, like:  self.value1 contains self.value2

Comment: what is data type of the value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97268/discussion-between-oleg-gordiichuk-and-arti).